# Codeigniter mpdf is not displaying images in live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

I have used mpdf for my codeigniter Project to print ticket with header image and it is working in my local machine while I moved source to test server, the images are not displaying in generated PDF.

Is the Permission issue? Is the invalid SSL issue?

Comment: Did you get this fixed? What was the issue? I'm currently running into this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the issue once. You may use the image extension `.jpg`. It seems mpdf in some live server only accepts `.jpeg` images. Check with `.jpeg` images

**Note:** Don't just manually change the extension. The mime type should be of `jpeg` image(`image/jpeg`).

Comment: Thanks @Arun, the above solution worked for me in CodeIgniter 3 on AWS.